# numeric Json decode not work

Tags: php

i have below json code

```
 {"1":1,"5":1}
```

when i decode the above json i got object array using the below php statement.

```
$array_val = (array)json_decode($price);
```

i got a below  array.

```
Array
(
  [1] => 1
  [5] => 1
)
```

but the below statement does not work

```
echo $array_val[1];
```

the below error occurred.
Undefined offset: 1

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this [DEMO](https://3v4l.org/ThLNS)

PHP

```
$json = '{"1":1,"5":1}';
$array_val=json_decode($price, true);
echo $array_val[1];
```

OUTPUT :

```
1
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that json_decode($string) returns an object, not an array (which is why your code doesn't behave).

To return an array instead, use:

```
$arr = json_decode($string, true);
```

See also http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 3):

You can get this using below code

```
$array_val=json_decode($price);
echo $array_val->{1}
```

OR

```
$array_val=json_decode($price,true);
echo $array_val[1]
```